# How to(Can I) get the content of other section from a NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data

Suppose I have a database table like this:

```
| id   | gender|  
|------|-------|  
| 0001 | Male  |  
| 0002 | Male  |  
| 0003 | Female|  
| 0004 | Female|
```

And I use NSFetchedResultsController with "id" as NameKeyPath to fetch four sections:

```
var fetchedID = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, 
    managedObjectContext: managedContext,
    sectionNameKeyPath: "id", cacheName: nil)
do {
    try fetchedDay.performFetch()
} catch {
    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
}
```

I know I can get id with this:

```
var ID = fetchedID.sections![0].name
```

**The problem is: I also want to get the gender of every id at the same time.**

Can I?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "id" as the `sectionNameKeyPath` will you a separate section per unique id, grouping all instances with the same ID into a single group.  Since id is probably unique, that means each group will be a single record.  Rather than grouping on a unique field, just to specify something for `sectionNameKeyPath`, it's usually better to just specify `nil`

Within each section, you'll get the full record, so you can use    `fetchedID.sections![n]` to return to the `nth` section, and can fetch individual records with `fetchedID.sections![x].objects![y]` to fetch the `yth` object in the `xth` section.

Alternatively, you can fetch all records, independent of sections, with the `fetchedObjects` property of the FetchedResultsController: `fetchedID.fetchedObjects[n]`